# listen to messages using pusher in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, real-time, pusher

I need to get echo message in the log when there is massage has been set to me  can I listen to the message that has been sent to me through this code

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = false;

var pusher = new Pusher('34b9ea6826c359c41c3f', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('Messages');
channel.bind('msgSend{{$id}}msgReceive{{Auth::user()->id}}', function(data) {
    $('.adsx').append(data.html);
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $('.adsx')[0].scrollHeight}, 0);
});
```

Comment: What is your real problem ?

Comment: I need to listen when somebody sends me a message  @NikolasDiakosavvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a Laravel **Event** through artisan `php artisan make:event addANameHere`

Afterwards, inside the **event** you need to add a channel to be broadcast on 
e.g.

```
class addANameHere implements ShouldBroadcast {

use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $user_id;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($user_id)
{
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['alert-user-'.$this->user_id];
}
```

Then, you can receive messages like that:

```
var pusher = new Pusher("34b9ea6826c359c41c3f", {
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: false,
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('alert-user-{{ Auth::user()->id }}');
channel.bind('App\\Events\\addANameHere', function(data) {
    // Do whatever you want here ...
});
```

In order to trigger that event (When the message is sent) you call your Event Class like that:

```
 \Event::dispatch(new addANameHere($user_id));
```

And the `$user_id` is the user you want to see that message.

I hope I helped..